# GUI interface to build a histogram via a data with change able bin in matlab

Tags: user-interface, matlab, histogram

I am trying to build up a GUI interface similar to the figure.[image]

Basically, I need to have two panels. The panel on the left shows the x,y scatter plot of my data, the panel on the right shows the corresponding histogram of y values. Furthermore, on the bottom of the histogram panel, I want to have a drag to change the bin size. Once I change the bin size, the histogram panel will update automatically. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [scatterhist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/scatterhist.html) to create the scatter plot and a histogram next to it. To add a slider to the same figure, you can do:

```
uicontrol(gcf, 'Style', 'slider', 'Position', [120 20 120 20])
```

where you would have to specify a better position yourself.